# Site not working properly on Plesk Server

Tags: web, prestashop, e-commerce, plesk

I've got an ecommerce shop that uses Prestashop 1.7.6.3

We've got 2 sites, the main site and the dev site.

One day, the dev site was perfectly working and all of a sudden it stopped working from one day to another. The front office and the back office, both of them. They "work" but really really slow and the elements in the site have no style at all.

[Front office of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYd4x.png)

[Back office of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REp8Q.png)

My first thought was to do a back up of the site of production, which works perfectly. But it didn't work at all. We usually do it every month and we never have any issues, its true that is not the most perfect process (drag and dropping folders) but that's the way I'm told to do it.

Anyways the site was already like this before doing the "backup", so I guess that's not the issue. Although is not the best way of doing that kind of process.

This is the error, I've been receiving in my logs:

[Logs of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2sKJ.png)

I tried regenerating the .htaccess but it didn't work.

I also tried to install everything in a local machine but Xampp give me a lot of problems and I decided to give up in that fact.

Anyone that can help me with this issue?